# Cant open ports in VPS Win Server 2016(AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, vps

i'm trying to open ports 7171, 7172, 80 in Windows Server 2016 at AWS.

I already opened them in Firewall, then i tried to turn firewall off but i still unable to acess my xampp website through port 80 using my ip and cant acess my server at port 7171/72.

I enter at portchecker.co and he still saying that all of then are closed.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you open your Security Group ?

Comment: Actually, my firewall was set to off. So, this should open security group, right?

Comment: Nope, so security groups are AWS features while Firewall is the instance feature , you will have to make sure both are open

Comment: Hey Nishant, thanks for your help. Is there any tutorial to open security group? Thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps :

> 1. https://cloudacademy.com/blog/aws-security-groups-instance-level-security/
> 2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

This will help you understand how Security Groups work in AWS